# Loop in WordPress Page not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my page template:

It's not pulling the content in. Not sure what I'm missing?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <section id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row divide">
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What page template? What page are you trying to visit? What should be appearing? What post type are you trying to view?

Comment: this is just my page.php file in WordPress. The content of the page should be appearing. Page post type.

Comment: @jeffbooher Your code is for particulate page data not for display list of post ? are you want to display list of post ?

Answer (score 0):

This code is for display post list in template. Please try it.

```
get_header();
?>
<section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row divide">
            <?php
            $args = array('post_type' => 'post');
            $postlist = new WP_Query($args);

            if ($postlist->have_posts()) {
                while ($postlist->have_posts()) {
                    $postlist->the_post();
                    the_title();
                    the_content();
                    // list posts here
                }

                // post pagination
            } else {
                // no posts content
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
        <section id="services">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row divide">

      <?php      if ( have_posts() ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
            //
            // Post Content here 
            //
            } // end while
            } // end if
       ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```